# Why won't my ImageButtons shuffle for my sliding puzzle game?

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a super simple 2x2 sliding puzzle using Android Studio.  Even though 2x2 isn't really recommended, I want to make this game as simple as possible.

In the content_game.xml file I created a 2x2 table using ImageButtons.  In my Game.java file, within the `OnCreate()` function I made references to each widget and created and called a `shuffle()` function to mix them up.  In that same activity I created a "New Puzzle" button to shuffle the images again.

FULL Game.java file:

```
        gameGrid[0][0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.square1);
        gameGrid[0][1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.square2);
        gameGrid[1][0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.square3);
        gameGrid[1][1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.square4);
        newPuzzleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newPuzzleBtn);
        movesTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movesTextView);

 //event handlers
        for (int x = 0; x < gameGrid.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < gameGrid[x].length; y++) {
                gameGrid[x][y].setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }

        newPuzzleButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        //scramble grid for new puzzle
        scramble();

        //starting values
        moves = 0;
        gameOver = false;
        imgName = "shoes"; //default puzzle img
        movesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(moves));
        gameString = "    "; //4 spaces (1 for each square)
    }

   private void scramble() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int x_index;
        int y_index;
        ImageButton temp[][] = new ImageButton[2][2];

        for (int x = gameGrid.length - 1; x > 0; x--) {
            for (int y = gameGrid[x].length - 1; y > 0; y--) {
                x_index = random.nextInt(x + 1);
                y_index = random.nextInt(y + 1);
                temp[x][y] = gameGrid[x_index][y_index];
                gameGrid[x_index][y_index] = gameGrid[x][y];
                gameGrid[x][y] = temp[x][y];
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.newPuzzleBtn:
                scramble();

                //set starting values
                moves = 0;
                gameOver = false;
                imgName = "shoes"; //default puzzle img
                movesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(moves));
                gameString = "    "; //4 spaces (1 for each square)
                break;
            default:
            ImageButton b = (ImageButton) v;
            if (b.getId() == R.id.square4) {
                moves = 4;
            }
            else if (b.getId() == R.id.square3){
                moves = 3;
            }
            else if (b.getId() == R.id.square2){
                moves = 2;
            }
            else {
                moves = 1;
            }
            movesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(moves));
        }
    }
```

FULL content_game_.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".Game"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_game">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movesTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="225dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableRow>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/square1"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:background="#ccc"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/square2"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:background="#ccc"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/square3"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:background="#ccc"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/square4"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:background="#ccc"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newPuzzleBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:text="@string/newPuzzleBtn"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

When I open the game, I expected the 2D array to be shuffled, but it doesn't turn out that way.  The pieces of each puzzle remain in the correct order.

EDIT:
Each ImageButton widget has a background set to each broken piece of the full image.

I've also tried to use this block of code alternatively within the `shuffle()` function but to no avail:

```
      int num;
        for (int x = gameGrid.length - 1; x > 0; x--) {
           for (int y = gameGrid[x].length - 1; y > 0; y--) {
               num = random.nextInt(y);
               if (num == 0) {
                   gameGrid[x][y] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.square1);
               }
               else if (num == 1) {
                   gameGrid[x][y] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.square2);
               }
               else if (num == 2) {
                   gameGrid[x][y] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.square3);
               }
               else {
                   gameGrid[x][y] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.square4);
               }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not shuffle the positions of the `ImageButton`s.

Similar situation: if you have the telephone numbers of four persons written down on a sheet of paper, shuffling the order in which they appear on the paper will not assign new numbers to the four persons.

I suppose you assigned each of the `ImageButton`s a fixed drawable resource. You can use a 2D array of drawable resources

```
private int[][] images = {R.drawable.top_left, R.drawable.top_right, R.drawable.bottom_left, R.drawable.bottom_right};
```

where top_left.png, top_right.png, bottom_left.png and bottom_right.png are the four parts of the puzzle.

If you shuffle *that* and assign the drawable resources to the `ImageButton`s afterwards, you should get the desired effect.

Please note that the loops in your scramble() should run to ">= 0" not "> 0".

Another approach to shuffle the image resources is to use a `SparseIntArray` which is similar to a `List` but works with the primitive data type `int` not with `Integer` . This can be useful to improve performance.

```
private SparseIntArray images = new SparseIntArray();
```

Let's introduce two new methods

```
private void initializeImages() {
    images.clear();
    images.append(0,R.drawable.ic_phone_24dp);
    images.append(1,  R.drawable.ic_face_24dp);
    images.append(2, R.drawable.ic_favorite_24dp);
    images.append(3, R.drawable.ic_star_24dp);
}
```

and

```
private void shuffleImageResourceIds() {
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int x = gameGrid.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        for (int y = gameGrid[x].length - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
            int size = images.size();
            if(size > 1){
                int index = random.nextInt(size);
                int imageResourceId = images.valueAt(index);
                images.removeAt(index);
                gameGrid[x][y].setImageResource(imageResourceId);
            }
            else {
                gameGrid[x][y].setImageResource(images.valueAt(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use them in `onCreate()`

```
newPuzzleButton.setOnClickListener(this);
//scramble grid for new puzzle
//scramble();
initializeImages();
shuffleImageResourceIds();
```

and in `onClick()`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.newPuzzleBtn:
            // scramble();
            initializeImages();
            shuffleImageResourceIds();

            //set starting values like before ...

            break;
        default:
           // handle moves like before ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this!  I created that private int and then shuffled them, while using `setImageResource(images[x][y])` within the nested for-loop, so that it'd run for the four parts.  When testing this, though, it only shows that the bottom-right corner's pictures has shuffled.  I've unassigned the fixed resources, so the app shows the first 3 boxes as blank while the 4th has a random piece. 
 Can you help me further?

Comment: @SyzzleFizz - please share the whole relevant code (not just snippets, and the xml file as well), then I'll look into it

Comment: Updated question with full .java and .xml code.  Again, thanks for taking the time.